# Java: How to Use Apache Shiro with Couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, shiro

I am interested in evaluating Apache Shiro for the authentication and authorization solution for a web application.  The underlying data store for the application is Couchbase 2.1.1.  However, I have yet to see seen how to configure Shiro to use a NoSQL document store such as Couchbase in any of the Shiro docs or getting started guides.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard for the Session Cache: on the `DefaultWebSessionManager` (or your implementation) call `setCache()` with your own implementation of a `CacheManager`.

On your implementation of `CacheManager`, override the method `public <K, V> Cache<K, V> getCache(String cacheName) throws CacheException` to return your `Cache` implementation.

This `Cache` implementation must handle the calls to CouchBase.
Now you have to make sure that your `HttpSession`s are serializable.

If you want to cache Authorization and Authentication infos, you have to basically do the same on your implementation of the `AuthorizingRealm``

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Shiro, but I see that you have some plugins to integrate Memcached and Shiro. you can use this to connect/cache data in Couchbase, since Couchbase is compliant with the memcached protocol